# browsers do not fetch any javascript file in a specific domain

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, javascript

I am running `ubuntu 20.04`
I have problem while opening [beisat.org](https://beisat.org)
When I view page source there is no `<script>` tag and no js file is loaded.
But I can load other websites correctly. Also I have checked this [beisat.org](https://beisat.org) in other devices like my phone and some others. This is working fine and there is a problem only on my laptop.

This is the error in console of firefox. I have tried chrome and opera. They have the same issue.
error: `Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.`

I used `wget` and downloaded [beisat.org](https://beisat.org). Then opened the `index.html`, then in view page source I can see there are many `<script>` tags and the javascript is loaded correctly.

I also have a windows installation on my laptop. This problem does not appear in windows for me.

Comment: Have you tried spoofing the useragent to trick the website?

Comment: @mchid actually it worked. I used this extension in firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uaswitcher/ and loaded the website in windows. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mchid for the simple solution.

You just need to **change the user agent in your browser**.
Find an extension to change it for you on the go.

- FireFox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uaswitcher/
- Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg